# JSDoc to describe a React useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsdoc

How do you describe a React state using JSDoc?

In other words, how do you simplify this into a one-liner?

```
/** The animal you're with */
let animal;
let setAnimal;
[animal, setAnimal] = useState()
```

In yet other words...

```
/** what do you put here to describe `animal`? */
const [animal, setAnimal] = useState()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  /**
   * @typedef Man
   * @property {string} name
   * @property {number} age
   */

  /**
   * @type {[Man, React.Dispatch<Man>]}
   */
  const [data, setData] = useState({ name: "ben", age: 20 });
```

Comment: Thanks sutie, but all I'm after is to describe your `data`, which you don't seem to have in your example? And I think if you use TypeScript, all you need to do is `const [data, setData] = useState<Man>({ name: "ben", age: 20 });`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).